# ActionController::Parameters 'require' method returns a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

On the `create` method of my controller, trying to setup required and permitted parameters fail:

```
  params.fetch(:xyz, {}).require(:name).permit(:local)
```

returns

```
  undefined method `permit' for "EXAMPLE":String Did you mean? print
```

params originally is

```
"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"...",
"xyz"=>{"name"=>"EXAMPLE", "local"=>""},
"commit"=>"Create xyz"}
```

I even tried to create new Parameters object, but no change:

```
  ActionController::Parameters.new(params.fetch(:dispensary, {})).require(:name).permit(:local)
```

Can someone shed a light on this? I'm new to Rails, sorry.

Comment: @spickermann I'm sanitizing input from an html form. Rails Tutorial seems to do the same. Is this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax would be:

```
params.require(:xyz).permit(:local, :name)
```

Comment: Removing the fetch gives me `ActionController::ParameterMissing in XyzController#create`. Sorry, I'm new to this.

Comment: That means that there wasn't a `:xyz` found in the `params`. Can you please show your whole controller action?

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at [Rails guides - Strong Parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) and it gives a good example and explanation of how to get params. So your code should look like:

```
def xyz_params
  params.require(:xyz).permit(:name, :local)
end
```